# Laravel 5.4 - unable to catch all exceptions

Tags: laravel, exception, try-catch

On Laravel 5.4, I'm using a console command of my own. This command is a scheduled task (every minute). This task instantiates a library. In this library, the very first thing I'm doing is:

```
try {
    $this->doSomething1();
    $this->doSomething2();
    ...
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    ...
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

Most of the times, the exceptions are caught, my code keeps running smoothly.
But sometimes, it isn't caught. For example, I had an exception yesterday because I was trying to insert a longtext into a text field in MySQL who complained about it. The exception was not raised and my command aborted.

What am I missing? How can I catch all the exception at once?
Thanks a lot,

Axel

Comment: are `doSomething1()` and `doSomething2()` methods both are set to `throw new Exception` on error?

Comment: doSomething() can run Laravel query builder commands that should raise exceptions themselves. It can also throw new Exception

Comment: In my opinion catching `\Exception` is enough, that is the parent of all exception. Unless after catch exception something throwing an exception.

Comment: That's what I thought too but something seems to be not working here.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem when forcing an error. This is what I get in my console `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::diffForHuman() in /var/www/Deploy.php:516`. This is a little bit different as this is a PHP Fatal Error but still, it says "Uncaught Exception". Very weird isn't it?